# How to call a route at a particular time

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I have a MERN stack Library Management System website.

In my app currently for admin i have given a `Notify` button to send emails to all user that have any books due in the library. For this an array of defaulty user gets passed as a req body to send emails. Admin gets this list of users from database on initial render of that particular component.

But i want to automate sending of emails and want my server to trigger automatic emails at 10:00 am to all the users who have due books.

On `Notify` button click my `notifyBookDefaulties` controller gets triggered.

I tried to use a setTimeout and a timer as well to call my route at 10:00 am and trigger emails but i am not able to get desired output.

Below i my notifyBookDefaulties controller:

```
const notifyBookDefaulties = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const admin = await Auth.findById(req.user.id);
  // to check if user exists by that id in the databse
  // and that user is a admin (got by token)
  if (!admin && admin.admin !== true) {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("Not Authorized");
  }
  const { users, bookID, title } = req.body; // here users is the list of user id's
  let emails = "";
  // to get email of each user from their user id
  for (let user of users) {
    try {
      const defaulty = await Auth.findById(user);
      emails += defaulty.email + ",";
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400);
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  }
  // to get comma separated list of emails
  const emailList = emails.slice(0, -1).toString();
  // try block tries to send email and catch block catches any error if occured
  try {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: process.env.SERVICE,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.USER,
        pass: process.env.PASS,
      },
    });
    var mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.USER,
      to: emailList,
      subject: "Return Book",
      html: `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><body>This is to remind you that the book titled ${title} and ID ${bookID} issued by you is due.</body></html>`,
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
      if (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ msg: error });
      } else {
        res.status(200).json({ msg: "E-Mail Successfully sent" });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ msg: error });
  }
});
```

Below is my server.js:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const { errorHandler } = require("./middleware/errorMiddleware");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const cors = require("cors");
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

  connectDB();
  
  const app = express();
  
  const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204
  };

  app.use(cors(corsOptions))
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

  app.use("/api/admin", require("./routes/adminRoutes"));
  app.use("/api/user", require("./routes/userRoutes"));
  app.use("/api/actions", require("./routes/authRoute"));

  app.use(errorHandler);

  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Running on ${port}`);
  });
```

My controller gets called for below route:

```
router.post("/notify", protect, notifyBookDefaulties);
```

and the url is:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/admin/notify
```

Note: here i have not included my function which fetches the list of user id's, of users that have due books. To fetch defaulting users i have a separate controller and i will merge that into this controller once i get the logic to send mails at 10:00 am.

If there is any other way to implement this i would like to know. If any more clarity needed do tell. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use any job scheduler library like [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule), [agenda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cron job, check this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron